# Model property dependent on request

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to implement this:

```
class Job(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    ...

    @property
    def mine(self):
        return owner == request.user
```

How can I access the request from the model?

Comment: You can't access request from the model, you need to pass the `request.user` as an argument to the function.